# Make Facebook Fan Page into iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I would like to make a Facebook fan page into a stand-alone iOS app.

Is there an easy way or template to make it so?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a nice question... +1

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do this is, create a project with only one view drag and drop UIWebView and just link your Facebook fan page to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no.

But there are a lot of tools to ease the pain from '[no coding required](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/13_tools_for_building_your_own_iphone_app.php)' to [phoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) (wraps your html, css and javascript for the iPhone) and [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) (compiles your html, css and js to native app code).